# Updating local storage value with array

Tags: javascript, jquery, local-storage

I created some form that after submit is storing some data in `localstorage` as an array:

```
var anInput = {'name':'John', 'age':'23'};
if(localStorage.getItem("artikli") === null) {
    var artikal = [anInput];
    localStorage.setItem("artikli", 
    JSON.stringify(artikli));
} else {
    var artikli = localStorage.getItem("artikli"),
    a = JSON.parse(artikli),
    b = a.replace(/\[|\]/g, ""),
    artikal = [b,anInput];
}
```

I tried this but I get error:

> a.replace is not a function

I am trying on new form submit to update existing item in localstorage.

Comment: What is purpose of `b = a.replace(/\[|\]/g, ""), artikal = [b,anInput]`?

Comment: I am trying to get array from localstorage as: [{'name':'John', 'age':'23'}], because in localstorage its like that, and then I want to put that in some var and remove []  so I can make another array with existing object and new object and overwrite existing item in localstorage

Comment: Don't use replace or other string functionality to mess around with JSON - use the proper methods that exist for the purpose of de- and encoding it.

Comment: @NoNameIamLame After you call `JSON.parse()`, you no longer have a JSON string, you have the object that it represents. There are no more square brackets in it. You should manipulate it as objects and arrays.

Comment: @CBroe String methods can be utilized to parse `JSON`. `JSON` is a string.

Comment: @Barmar but why then I got it as array and obj in it, by my way of doing it and getting new array with existing obj and new one I got array in array which was existing obj and new obj I will ss and put in question.

Comment: @NoNameIamLame Why do you need to remove existing array? What is expected result of `localStorage.getItem("artikli")` at conclusion of `else` block?

Comment: @NoNameIamLame You're making it too complicated. See my answer, it's very simple.

Comment: @Barmar you are probably right I never see simple things even if they are in front of me...

Comment: @guest271314 they can be, and they shouldn't. Makes it just too easy to mess up when it comes to data that needs specific escaping, etc.

Comment: @CBroe "shouldn't" is far too restrictive a suggestion? `JSON` rules are minimalist; double quote property names; use `try..catch..finally` to check if adjusted `JSON` is valid. "mess up" can occur at any procedure, whether the taskis "easy" or not.

Comment: @guest271314 the _right_ tool for the job exists, and it is designed to properly handle all edge cases. That you _can_ write your own "solution" that will either fail for certain edge cases, or will get bloated while trying to cover them, doesn't mean you should.

Comment: @CBroe Do not agree. Both `RegExp` and `String` methods can be utilized to adjust `JSON`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you call `JSON.parse()`, you have an array, not a JSON string. You can use normal array operations on this -- use `.push()` to add a new object to the array.

```
var anInput = {'name':'John', 'age':'23'};
var json = localStorage.getItem("artikli");
if (json) {
    artikli = JSON.parse(json);
} else {
    artickli = [];
}
artikli.push(anInput);
localStorage.setItem("artikli", JSON.stringify(artikli));
```